# pairwise factors/categorical variables contingency table from dataframe with more than 2 columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several columns of categorical covariates. I am trying to generate n choose 2 tables,

`table(df[[1]],df[[2]])
table(df[[1]],df[[3]])
...
table(df[[n-1]],df[[n]])`

I tried using outer as `outer(df,df,table)` but I get an error which I am pretty certain is because it would  use single brackets instead of double brackets.

I also tried using `combn(df,2)`, but it loses the factor names.

Should I simply use loops? I have been recommended against this in favour of vectorization, but if it is equally efficient then it would suffice.

I should mention I also tried `xtabs(~., df)` but this I think not only generated the tables, but also the thousnads of  marginal contingency tables.

Any help regarding vectorization, or these functions would be useful

EDIT: I managed to do it using xtabs, and using as.formula by pasting the ith and jth variable names as into a formula separated by "+" in a nested for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping inefficiency should be of no concern because the loops will not be large.  However, the `apply` family of functions is both expressive and convenient, so it is worth considering.  It avoids having to pre-allocate data structures for the result and it avoids a cumbersome double loop.

I will illustrate with a toy dataset, taking one step at a time.  Let's create a data frame `df` with three columns named "x", "y", and "z":

```
> n <- 1:5; (df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x=n, y=n*10, z=n*100)))

  x  y   z
1 1 10 100
2 2 20 200
3 3 30 300
4 4 40 400
5 5 50 500
```

An array of distinct pairs of names of `df` is readily produced with `combn`, as suggested in the question:

```
> combn(names(df), 2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "x"  "x"  "y" 
[2,] "y"  "z"  "z"
```

You can use each column to index into the columns of `df`:

```
> apply(combn(names(df), 2), 2, function(i) df[i])

[[1]]
  x  y
1 1 10
2 2 20
3 3 30
4 4 40
5 5 50

[[2]]
  x   z
1 1 100
2 2 200
3 3 300
4 4 400
5 5 500

[[3]]
   y   z
1 10 100
2 20 200
3 30 300
4 40 400
5 50 500
```

The result is a list of data frames, each with suitably named columns.  You may therefore invoke `lapply` to generate the tables.  Here is the full solution.  It produces a list of tables.

```
>  lapply(apply(combn(names(df), 2), 2, function(i) df[i]), table)

[[1]]
   y
x   10 20 30 40 50
  1  1  0  0  0  0
  2  0  1  0  0  0
  3  0  0  1  0  0
  4  0  0  0  1  0
  5  0  0  0  0  1

[[2]]
   z
x   100 200 300 400 500
  1   1   0   0   0   0
  2   0   1   0   0   0
  3   0   0   1   0   0
  4   0   0   0   1   0
  5   0   0   0   0   1

[[3]]
    z
y    100 200 300 400 500
  10   1   0   0   0   0
  20   0   1   0   0   0
  30   0   0   1   0   0
  40   0   0   0   1   0
  50   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: This may be a much more elegant solution than mine with pasting formulas. Will have to check back later.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this with some FP magic by using the Map function, like so:

```
Map(function(n) table(a[[n[1]]], a[[n[2]]]), combn(colnames(a), 2, simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: It is not incorrect. I would want , (1,2),(1,3),...,(1,n),(2,3),(2,4),...,(2,n),...,(n-1,n)

Appreciated regardless

Comment: @Level126 OK, then "n choose 2 tables" is incorrect. I guess my logic falters as well since my former solution would give you n-1 tables. ;) Anyhow, I have updated my response with an alternative to whuber's answer. Cheers!